# Animate Using setScale()

Tags: android, andengine

I want to animate my player from **bigger size to smaller size** and then **smaller size to bigger size** continuously. 
We can use **setScale()** method to re-size any sprite but is there any way to animate with it?

And one more thing, if I scale any sprite **after creating it's physics body**, the sprite is visually scaled but the physics body **does not** scaled.

So is there any optimum solution to animate the physics body from bigger to smaller and then smaller to bigger?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why not scale both the physics body *and* the sprite?

Comment: You want to look into linear interpolation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use entity modifier for this purpose.

For example,

```
sprite.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(new SequenceEntityModifier(new ScaleModifier(1,1,1.5),new ScaleModifier(1,1.5,1))));
```

Above code can become useful to you. If you found any mistake then please make it correct because I don't check it.

And now turn for body, as per my suggestion you have to create different body each time to show scale up and down. You can write this code in managerUpdate method. One thing also you can check that change fixturedef of the body and try to create new body in that way also. Whatever choice you like.

Answer (score -3):

`sprite.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(new SequenceEntityModifier(new ScaleModifier(1,1,(float)1.5),new ScaleModifier(1,(float)1.5,1))));`

Comment: Please explain what this code is doing; it's not very obvious